# How a decoder converts the lower dimension to higher dimension in autoencoders?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, autoencoder

I am building an autoencoder . I have read on the google that encoder compresses the data like converting the 784 no of dimensions to 100 no of hidden neurons of bottleneck and then decoder converts that 100 no of dimensions to 784 again , i want to know that how it (decoder) converts to higher dimension from lower dimension because if we talk about encoder it may reduces the number of bits by eliminating some redundant bits and chooses what features should be thrown away and what aspects can be relevant. But How lower dimension converts into higher again , either it is by again adding that bits which we had thrown away in the encoder or by something else . Kindly elaborate

Comment: The idea is that since pixels of an image are not independent of each other, the original image often has lower effective dimensionality than 784.  Imagine for example an extreme case where all images have a black horizontal line on the white background.   Then the image can be expressed by a single number (height of the line), i.e. the dimension is one.  The auto-encoders does the same in a more complex manner.

Comment: But it'll give the output as a number of pixel not as the height of line .

Answer (score 0):

The confusion seems to have stemmed from assuming that the encoder and decoder are independent processes that are trained separately during the learning process—they are not. The model learns to encode and decode together. That is why the loss function in autoencoders, *L*(x,x̂ ), is a function of both the autoencoder input (original sample x) and output (reconstructed sample x̂). More details can be found [here](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/autoencoders/). Of course, once the model is trained, one may use each separately to encode or decode.

Answer (score 0):

## Autoencoders - how does the decoder part do?

Indeed the classic MNIST autoencoder takes in images of digits 28x28 in size (784 pixels) and we could define one in python like so

```
import tensorflow as tf

encoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid')
])

encoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(100,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(784),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((28,28)),
])

autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    encoder,
    decoder
])
```

It isn't the **best** but it'll do for our purpose.  Now imagine that the input isn't the MNIST handwritten digits, but a picture containing none or more of the following:

- a plus in the upper left hand corner
- a circle in the lower left hand corner
- a slash in the upper right hand corner
- a square in the lower right hand corner

and that each item doesn't overlap the others and is always the same.  If I was given this to **encode** I would turn each image into a boolean "encoding" of 4 data points, a true/false for each of the features.  If I was then asked to make a decoder that read the encoding and correctly re-created the original image, no problem again.  I would draw or not draw each glyph depending if the feature was true or false in my encoding.

What our above autoencoder can be fit/trained to do is something very similar.  It will use the encoder part to encode the most frequently used and reusable structures and patterns that exist in the picture.  The decoder will be used to take each feature and conditionally write pixels to the output image.

In our example `decoder` above, it has a dense(784) layer.  That layer has 100 inputs and 784 outputs, for a total internal weight matrix of shape 100x784.  That means for each embedding layer value it can modify some, none, or all the of the pixels of the output image.  This toy network will actually do amazing on the plus/circle/slash/square problem as the decoder can use each feature to write the important information (a whole reproduction of the original image) to the output.

Another way of thinking of out decoder with a weight matrix of 100x784, is that it has memorized 100 full variations of the entire 784 output image.